# Pass MKMapType variable from UISegmentedControl in FlipsideViewController to MainViewController

Tags: objective-c, methods, delegates, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview

I'm having trouble passing the index of a UISegmentedControl from FlipSideViewController.m to my MainViewController.m which holds my MKMapView.  Here is my code:

MainViewController.h

```
 @interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate> {
   MKMapView *mapView;
 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *mapType;

 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
 - (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;
 @end
```

FlipSideViewController.h

```
@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate;

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
  id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
  IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mapType_;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
  - (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *mapType_;
@end

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
    - (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
    - (void)flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:(int)index;
@end
```

FlipSideViewController.m

```
 - (IBAction)changeView {
  [delegate flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangesToIndex: mapType_.selectedSegmentIndex];
  }
```

MainViewController.m

```
- (void)flipsideViewControllerSelectionChangedToIndex:(int)index {
  if ( index == 0 )mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
  if ( index == 1 )mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
  if ( index == 2 )mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
 }
```

My problem is that in my simulator when I click any of the segments in the UISegmentedControl the application shuts down.  The console shows this error thrown:

```
-[FlipsideViewController changeView:]: unrecognized 
 selector sent to instance 0x6d43f30
2011-06-01 19:50:31.055 GermTracker2[893:207] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '-[FlipsideViewController changeView:]:   
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d43f30'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a double `@end` in your FlipSideViewController.h. Try removing `@end` after `- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;`

Comment: Ok that fixed that error but now in my simulator when I flip the view and click any of the UISegmentedControls the application closes unexpectedly

Comment: @Saphrosit -  I was in the process of doing so when you commented - I edited my OP to reflect the current error

Comment: Did you linked the UISegmentedControl correctly in your .xib file? Maybe at the beginning you defined `-(IBAction)changeView:(id)sender` and after you removed the sender as argument...That might be a cause...

Comment: So - should have the `:(id)sender` argument or not?

Comment: My `.xib` now has an outlet in the file's owner called `mapType_` which I connected to my UISegmentedControl eliminating the die error.  But when I click on a segment in the control and click done to flip back nothing has changed.  And when I flip back to flipsideview again the default 0 segment is selected again....

Comment: the `sender` argument is not necessary, so you may omit it if not needed (as in this case). In your .xib file you also have to (if you didn't) link the method to your UISegmentedControl, selecting the event on which you want to call the method. Are you still getting errors?